# ASP C# repeat code for every page_Load instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

How can I add code to the `Page_Load()` method for every instance of `System.Web.UI.Page` without repeating the code?

I want, everytime a page loads, for the code

```
Debug.WriteLine("hello");
// other stuff here
// lots of lines of code
```

to run.

so I have many web pages for example

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // don't want to have to repeat all that code above here

        // stuff that WebForm1 does
    }
}
```

How can I run the first snippet for each `Page_Load` event without repeating the code for every webform?

Comment: Use master page and write method in master page load event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 MasterPage.cs
 -----------------
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Debug.WriteLine("hello");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Simpler than I realised!